# Normal vector - should be row or column vector?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors, tensors

I read article about [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor) on wiki and find following formula at the top:

$$
\mathbf{T}^{(\mathbf n)}= \mathbf n \cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma}\quad \text{or} \quad T_j^{(n)}= \sigma_{ij}n_i.
$$

As far I understand $T^{(n)}$ is covariant (row; "horizontal") vector - we can find it explicit definition few lines above [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Transformation_rule_of_the_stress_tensor) on that wiki aritcle which looks as follows:

$$
\left[{\begin{matrix}
T^{(\mathbf n)}_1 & T^{(\mathbf n)}_2 & T^{(\mathbf n)}_3\end{matrix}}\right]=\left[{\begin{matrix}
n_1 & n_2 & n_3
\end{matrix}}\right]\cdot
\left[{\begin{matrix}
\sigma _{11} & \sigma _{12} & \sigma _{13} \\
\sigma _{21} & \sigma _{22} & \sigma _{23} \\
\sigma _{31} & \sigma _{32} & \sigma _{33} \\
\end{matrix}}\right]
$$

As we see to calculate it using matrix multiplication we need to assume that normal vector $\mathbf n$ is row vector (for column vector left-multiplication is not allowed).

As far I know typical vector is contravariant (column; "vertical") vector .

I wonder: what is the 'default' form of normal vector in math - is it column vector or it is row vector?

$$
\mathbf n =\qquad [n_1\ n_2\ n_3]\qquad or \qquad 
\begin{bmatrix}
n_1 \\
n_2 \\
n_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad ?
$$

Second question: Are there some advantages of using row vector?

Comment: Hint: examine how the components of $\mathbf n$ transform.

Comment: @amd how I can examine that? I also find [this article](https://www.continuummechanics.org/tractionvector.html) wher $T=\sigma\cdot n$ - Im a little confused - can you give me some link?

Comment: It is merely a convention and different branches use different conventions. Either way, the column version is the most common convention.

Comment: @KlaasvanAarsen it is not so easy. The vector covariance and contravariance is important. When we change `n` from row to column then stress tensor need to be redefined. Stress tensore is base for many important mechanics equations - if you redefine this stress tensor you needo to also redefine that equations (stress tensor is not allways simetric - eq for magnetic fluid equations). I don't think that n is row is coincidence - it probably have deep tensor-math meaning. And this is reason why I ask this question

Comment: Apparently 'continuum mechanics' uses different conventions than is usual, as mentioned on the talk page. In case of doubt, look at the tensor notation. For the article it means that every vector is a row vector. Consequently they must always be on the left side of multiplications with matrices.

Comment: Additionally, you emphasize contravariant and covariant, but these concepts are only relevant in non-standard coordinate systems. Apparently that is never the case in continuum mechanics, which is why indices are always at the bottom - contrary to the usual convention.

Comment: Admittedly, it is strange that the article doesn't mention anything about unusual conventions. But then, it is only a 'sub' page.

Comment: In cfd 'unusuall' cordinate systems are used quite often e.g. [here](http://fccr.ucsd.edu/pubs/LB04.pdf). I'm not sure yet about wiki-article - it is coincidence or not

Comment: @amd can I know what is your opinion?

Comment: You may want to ask on a forum that is more dedicated to continuum mechanics. Perhaps the Physics forum.

Comment: I would say that typically a normal vector is really a "covector" (i.e. a row-vector) since its purpose is to encode the tangent plane (which is the nullspace of the row-vector)

Comment: Similarly, the cross-product of two vectors is more naturally thought of as a covector.  In a physical setting, a good indication that a vector should be thought of as a covector rather than as a vector is that its units are $m^2$ rather than $m$.