# Dot product for covariant vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

The standard definition for dot product of two vectors $\vec a=[a^i]$ and $\vec b=[b^i]$ (notice upper index) (e.g. in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)) is right for contravariant vectors :

$$
\vec a \cdot \vec b = a^1 b^1 + \dots + a^n b^n
$$

**Questions:** But is this definition is correct for covariant vectors $\vec a=[a_i]$ and $\vec a=[a_i]$ (notice bottom index) ? 
If no, then what is right definition ?

Comment: As I understand it, we usually write $a\cdot b=a^ib_i=a^ig_{ij}b^j=a_kg^{ki}b_i$, where we sum over any repeated index, but such an index has to appear once in a subscript, once in a superscript.

Comment: @J.G. - as far I know the dot product operate on two vectors with same variance (eg. two column vectors) - don't confuse dot product with matrix/vector multiplication

Comment: You want the last expression I gave in the covariant case, or the penultimate one in the contavariant case.

Comment: ok sorry, I focus on $a^ib_i$ - are you sure it is right formula?

Comment: [Quite sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors#Covariant_and_contravariant_components_of_a_vector_with_a_metric); my original comment was tactful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO - this definition is not correct for covariant vectors - the right formula is

$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\vec a\cdot \vec b &=& 
    (g^{11}a_1+ g^{12}a_2+\dots+g^{1n}a_n)(g^{11}b_1+ g^{12}b_2+\dots+g^{1n}b_n)\\
&+& (g^{21}a_1+ g^{22}a_2+\dots+g^{2n}a_n)(g^{21}b_1+ g^{22}b_2+\dots+g^{2n}b_n) \\
&+& \dots\\
&+& (g^{n1}a_1+ g^{n2}a_2+\dots+g^{nn}a_n)(g^{n1}b_1+ g^{n2}b_2+\dots+g^{nn}b_n) \\
\end{array}
$$

where $g^{ij}$ is contravariant form of [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor)

Comment: Then you'd better have $\vec a\cdot\vec b = \sum g_{ij}a^ib^j$ in the first place.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think your formula is wrong - e.g. we have $(g^{11})^2a_1b_1$ in my formula (upper $^2$ is power - not index). Second thing: you use upper index instead bottom and vice versa.

Comment: I was talking about the dot product of *contravariant* vectors. You started with a formula that assumed $g_{ij}  = \delta_{ij}$ to start with. And your formula is totally wrong. For covariant vectors, it will be $\sum g^{ij}a_ib_j$, where $[g^{ij}]$ is the inverse matrix of $[g_{ij}]$. Before you tell me I'm wrong again, I am a differential geometer and was a professor for 40 years.

Comment: ok sorry I don't understand you. Hm... so if you so experienced geometer then may by you will also know the answer for my previous question [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3492423/605065) ?

Comment: @TedShifrin - there is also another thing - it looks like the WIKI article [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is wrong or is incomplete. Many (millions?) people use wiki site to get information (e.g. Engineers, IT, students, etc.) - may be in if you have some free time you will be so kind and correct/complette this article? It will help many peoples

Comment: What are you saying specifically is wrong? I personally would write vectors as column vectors because 99% of the world wants to write $y=Ax$ for linear equations, rather than $y=xA$. But I am not interested in rewriting Wikipedia unless I see a blatant error.

Comment: This is mostly at the level of introductory multivariable calculus/linear algebra, where we do not teach metric tensors. Why not look at the [Wiki article on those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor)?